# Callback after an Angular application has rendered

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to execute some code after every Angular app module on my site has finished rendering.

I want to do it globally for all modules, so I need to do it outside of a controller.

How can I execute a function at this event?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this to execute your code.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    //put your code here
   //This will fire if the view has finished loading
});
```

Comment: $scope is only available inside a controller.

Comment: I just gave you a ref. You could use it on $rootScope.

Comment: how can I get $rootScope off the Angular object?

Comment: Create a service and have the $rootscope passed. As services are singleton objects it will get you the access.

Comment: to create a service you need to be inside a module. If I make a fake module with the service and run it, nothing happens. I also tried using the angular injector, and got this: https://gist.github.com/JacksonGariety/8233678